# How can we resolve Unable to Locate element Exception while giving Xpath for go to Next page of a Website in Selenium Python Web Scraping?

Tags: python, selenium, web

```
search_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[3]/div[2]/section[2]/div[3]/a[2]/i')[1]
search_btn.click()  -> **This step is throwing error**
```

Resulting error :

> ```
> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div[3]/div[2]/section[2]/div[3]/a[2]/i"}
> ```

(Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)

Comment: find_element is a single element with no indexes.